# Which MahApps.Metro-files needs to be included with my application installer

Tags: installation, mahapps.metro

I'm creating an installer for my MahApps-application and I'm wondering which MahApps-files I should include in the installer.

The application seems to be working fine without the MahApps.Metro.XML but perhaps I'm missing something?

So which should I include?

- MahApps.Metro.dll
- MahApps.Metro.XML
- System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

Comment: You need only the dll files for the setup. The xml file contains documentation which you only will see in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Including MahApps.Metro.dll and System.Windows.Interactivity.dll is enough, you don't need any other files.